# SSRS: error setting up the mapping

Tags: xml, reporting-services, import, xsd

This is my first time trying to use an XML source for a data transformation package in SSRS, so there is probably something simple I am overlooking.  I'd appreciate any help in identifying a cause and fix.

I'm trying to import an item catalogue from GS1.  I have an extensive xsd that describes over 200 individual attributes.  When I try to use it (and an accompanying data file) as an XML Source Data Flow Source, I am getting the following (unhelpful) error:

> Error at Load Products from XML [XML Source[1]]: There was an error setting up the mapping.  The {max occurs} of all the particles in the {particles} of an all group must be 0 or 1.

I have no idea what this means.  There are multiple individual items in each xml file (about 10,000 really) if that means anything.  I can post the xsd if desired, but be forewarned it is quite large.

Comment: Can you share sample code that you are using in your report dataset and datasource

Comment: @Aftab  What do you mean?  I'm not using anything in SQL to attempt to parse the files - just the XML Source widget in SSRS.  The stylesheet was provided by the source along with the data.